Jenkins Error on node launch - Remote call to ${NODE_NAME}
I've recently taken over a Jenkins instance that runs our C++ data pipeline on a nightly basis, but I'm a Jenkins noob. We had to let the previous engineer go and discovered that he was using personal keys fir GitHub and AWS, so deactivating his accounts broke our builds. I updated the keys to use service accounts and deploy keys, but now all of our nodes error on launch.
We have a single EC2 Ubuntu node (named dinky-launcher) that we leverage to spawn new EC2 instances on demand for our jobs to run on. Then this dinky-launcher node come up, we get the following exception (included a few lines beforehand too):
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Remoting version: 3206.vb_15dcf73f6a_9
Launcher: SSHLauncher
Communication Protocol: Standard in/out
This is a Unix agent
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to dinky-launcher
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1317)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectComputerListener.onOnline(EnvInjectComputerListener.java:144)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:751)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:441)
        at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startAgent(SSHLauncher.java:645)
        at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.lambda$launch$0(SSHLauncher.java:465)
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private native java.lang.reflect.Field[] java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @370a2c53
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.getModifiers(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:55)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Agent successfully connected and online

When we start a new job, Jenkins launches a new EC2 instance from one of our custom AMIs. Those instances also throw the below exception on launch and they never run the script configured in the job.
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to EC2 (mindevimage-ec2-jenkins-agents) - medium 256 jenkins worker (i-005bbc4ecf73b5729)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1283)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectComputerListener.onOnline(EnvInjectComputerListener.java:144)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:747)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:437)
        at hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.launchScript(EC2UnixLauncher.java:284)
        at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:48)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:297)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private native java.lang.reflect.Field[] java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @70fef5cc
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.getModifiers(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:55)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.call(EnvInjectMasterEnvVarsSetter.java:19)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

This was working right before we let this guy go. As far as I know, nothing changed except credentials, which I have verified all work just fine. We disabled the departed engineer's credentials before he was able to get in to do anything and he was the only other person with access this system aside from myself, so I'm at a loss here. I updated Jenkins today and have restarted both the master and slave, to no avail. I've spent the better part of 2 days here and have asked questions in multiple forums with zero replies.

Check your credential from Manage Jenkins > Credentials ,check the AWS and Github key are associated to correct account.
Also check the SSH configuration in Manage Jenkins > Manage Node . Check the name, Key and Host configuration.
Also update the jenkins plugins and check the Java version
And if not resolve try to create a new AMI
